# Dynamic subject for form notification email

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Is there a way to have a dynamic notification subject in Sprout Forms via custom fields, eg if I have a field called `subject` can I use this in the Subject option under Notifications as `{{ subject }}`?

Comment: Some progress - was using {{ subject }} when in fact should have been using { subject }. The next question is whether you can have conditional logic (eg `if subject then X otherwise Y`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the value of your custom field `subject` in two ways:

**Shorthand Syntax:**

```
{subject}
```

**Object Syntax**

```
{{ object.subject }}
```

If you want to perform any conditional logic, you will need to use object syntax for the conditional logic:

```
{% if object.subject != '' %}{{ object.subject }}{% else %}Fallback{% endif %}
```